# Why does 'git branch -r --contains' give this?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm using `git branch -r --contains <SHA1 Hash>` to deduce what commits went on which branch. For changes to master it gives:

```
git branch -r --contains efdf37fd440f79a6f728412b612d3624790eb62f
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/master
```

Why is `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` there & can I get rid of it?  For commits on a branch it only shows `origin/<branch name>` - which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

`origin/HEAD` just points to the "default" branch on the remote repo (the one that will be checked out when you clone the repo), so it's fine for it to contain the commit if `origin/master` also contains it.

Comment: This makes sense and reinforces my understanding.  I guess the "->" is the source of my confusion.  Can you lend any clarity on that?  I mean HEAD is a pointer to the default branch, but it's not really a branch in & of itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean it up by (assumes no branch names have -> in them):

```
 git branch -r --contains efdf37fd440f79a6f728412b612d3624790eb62f | grep -v '\->'
```